# BigQuery: flatten table with Array inside Array

Tags: arrays

trying to flatten the table with 2 deep Arrays

The schema:

[image]

I get an error:

[image]

Can't figure out what's the problem?

Please, help

The script

```
 #video_play_curve
  SELECT
    ad_id
    ,vpc.value
  FROM
    `foam-193716.foam_facebook_ads2.ads_insights`
    ,UNNEST( video_play_curve_actions.value.value ) vpc2
    ,UNNEST( video_play_curve_actions ) vpc
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 

ad_id
,date_start
,vpc.value.action_type
,vpcv.value
,video_view_duration_step

FROM
`foam-193716.foam_facebook_ads2.ads_insights` t
,unnest( t.video_play_curve_actions) vpc
,unnest( vpc.value.value) vpcv  WITH OFFSET AS video_view_duration_step
```